# How to configure ANSI text colors for NixOS console?

Tags: terminal, nixos, ansi

I'm on NixOS-unstable (as of 2023 Oct 1st). How can I configure the text colors for the default NixOS console, as the terminal supports ANSI?

I tested what the colors look like by installing [`text-ansi`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-ansi) on Haskell (GHC) and then putting some code snippets on GHCi, like `putStrLn $ red "Hello, world!"`.

I want to configure the colors because it's slightly hard to visually distinguish between some colors, `red` and `brightRed` for example. I'm gonna be annoyed when, for example, playing NetHack. Here's how I want to configure the colors:

- `black` = `#18270f`
- `red` = `#ff0111`
- `green` = `#2e8011`
- `yellow` = `#b25e3a`
- `blue` = `#0f87fe`
- `magenta` = `#c900ff`
- `cyan` = `#41ff1a`
- `white` = `#eca2ff`
- `brightBlack` = `#000074`
- `brightRed` = `#ff9700`
- `brightGreen` = `#b6ff00`
- `brightYellow` = `#fff86b`
- `brightBlue` = `#00e2ff`
- `brightMagenta` = `#ff0084`
- `brightCyan` = `#00ffa5`
- `brightWhite` = `#e4fffd`

(Yes, I know, some colors don't quite fit literally, but believe me, I acquired them from savage computation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set them in [`console.colors`](https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=23.05&show=console.colors&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=console.colors), like [this](https://gitlab.com/engmark/root/-/blob/a78f6e42cc0ba48ece104ddccd203871f60911e9/configuration.nix#L27-45):

```
{
  console.colors = [
    "073642"
    "dc322f"
    "859900"
    "b58900"
    "268bd2"
    "d33682"
    "2aa198"
    "eee8d5"
    "002b36"
    "cb4b16"
    "586e75"
    "657b83"
    "839496"
    "6c71c4"
    "93a1a1"
    "fdf6e3"
  ];
}
```